# Is there a way to convert fugit Instant to micoseconds?

Tags: rust, rp2040

I am using rp2040 and rp2040_hal and it uses fugit. I am using a function `timer.get_conter()` which returns a Instant of Fugit and I want to convert that Instant to a microseconds passed since start of micro-controller. Is there a way in fugit itself to achieve that?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the documentation of this `Instant` type?

Comment: https://docs.rs/fugit/0.1.2/fugit/struct.Instant.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you linked to it seems that you should do the following things:

1. Get `Duration` between two `Instant`s (for example using [`Instant::checked_duration_since`](https://docs.rs/fugit/0.1.2/fugit/struct.Instant.html#method.checked_duration_since)
2. Get number of `ticks` in this duration using [`Duration::ticks`](https://docs.rs/fugit/0.1.2/fugit/struct.Duration.html#method.ticks)
3. Calculate duration in seconds with formula stated in documentation: `duration in seconds = NOM / DENOM * ticks`
4. Convert it to microseconds by multiplying it by `1_000_000`